# Java divide operation exception

Tags: java, divide

Given following codes:

```
  long testNum = 1000;
  double midNum = testNum/60000;
  System.out.println(midNum);
  long another = Math.round(7600/midNum);
  System.out.println(another);
```

The output is:

```
0.0
9223372036854775807
```

1. Why the first output is `0.0`? How could I get the right result in java?
2. Since the first output is `0`, why the next expression has an result? Shouldn't it throw out an `by zero` expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the first output is 0.0?

You are using integer division so this is the right result.

> How could I get the right result in java?

Don't use integer division, use floating point instead, the simplest way to to make one of the value a floating point like this.

```
double midNum = testNum/60000.0;
```

or

```
double midNum = testNum/60e3;
```

> Since the first output is 0, why the next expression has an result?

Floating point arithmetic uses IEEE-754 standard (sometimes called IEEE-753.99999999999998 ;)
In floating point, you never get an exception in Java, you might get infinity, negative infinity or NaN.

Integers don't have Infinity, or NaN and have no way to represent this, so it produced an Exception.

When you round any number too big for a `long` it gives you the closest presentable value which is Long.MAX_VALUE

BTW

```
long l = Math.round(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY); // l == Long.MAX_VALUE
long l = Math.round(Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY); // l == Long.MIN_VALUE
long l = (long) Double.NaN; // l == 0
```

From `Double` you might find this interesting.

```
public final class Double extends Number implements Comparable<Double> {
    /**
     * A constant holding the positive infinity of type
     * {@code double}. It is equal to the value returned by
     * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff0000000000000L)}.
     */
    public static final double POSITIVE_INFINITY = 1.0 / 0.0;

    /**
     * A constant holding the negative infinity of type
     * {@code double}. It is equal to the value returned by
     * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0xfff0000000000000L)}.
     */
    public static final double NEGATIVE_INFINITY = -1.0 / 0.0;

    /**
     * A constant holding a Not-a-Number (NaN) value of type
     * {@code double}. It is equivalent to the value returned by
     * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7ff8000000000000L)}.
     */
    public static final double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0;

    /**
     * A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type
     * {@code double},
     * (2-2<sup>-52</sup>)&middot;2<sup>1023</sup>.  It is equal to
     * the hexadecimal floating-point literal
     * {@code 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023} and also equal to
     * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x7fefffffffffffffL)}.
     */
    public static final double MAX_VALUE = 0x1.fffffffffffffP+1023; // 1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Comment: Then based on the first result `0.0`, why it did not throw out an exception in the second `println`?

Comment: @Liquid The more interesting question is why 9223372036854775807 exactly ;) I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

long is can't hold decimals. Long is equal to int just with a higher range.

You should use decimal or float.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first result is `0.0` is due to your use of implicit casting. When dividing a long by a number, Java assumes that number is of the same type and will do "long" division, which has no remainder. Since 1000/60000 is between 0 and 1, the result is effectively floored to 0, and cast to 0.0 when it's a double. You can fix this by changing a line to `double midNum = testNum/60000D;`

Note the "D" at the end, indicating that 60000 is a double. This will force the long to be cast as a double and give the proper result.

For the second part, you're basically dividing by a very very small number, making it appear to be quite large. `0.0` cannot be represented accurately by a double, so you're actually dividing by something slightly above 0.0, which will be fixed when you fix the other part.

Comment: "`0.0` cannot be represented accurately by a double" - are you sure?

Answer (score 0):

use type cast operator.
 double midNum = (double)testNum/60000;